# Get the number of rows from ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get the number in ResultSet that I am getting from my query as in the code below. The query retrieves the number 5. How can I get this number from ResultSet?

**Code:**

```
String sql_count_stop = "select count(*) FROM behaviour where  mac = ? ";
PreparedStatement preparedCount = con.prepareStatement(sql_count_stop);
preparedCount.setString(1, macD);
ResultSet rsCount = preparedCount.executeQuery();
while(rsCount.next()){

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `ResultSet::getInt(String)` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your query to

```
"SELECT count(*) AS totalCount FROM behaviour WHERE mac = ? ";
```

and then use,

```
macId= rsCount.getInt("totalCount");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use position `rsCount.getInt(1)` and you don't need a column alias.

Also since there will be only one row, `if(rsCount.next())` is just as good as `while`, and in my opinion more clearly shows this logic will only execute once.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you SQL statement to: (added `AS 'countMacs'`)

```
select count(*) as 'countMacs' FROM behaviour where  mac = ?
```

Then get a value

```
while(rsCount.next()){
  int count = rsCount.getInt("countMacs");
}
```